# How to assign case comments to a existing case

Tags: apex, soql, community, email2case

i got a requirement i stuck in a place.

My requirement is

We have a email to case option available in sfdc. So, case has been created in sfdc.

But once support executive got a resolution for the case.Once he updates we write a time trigger and sent an email to customer and auto update case in 24 hours.But when customer replies it automatically created a case in sfdc.

Is there any solution to prevent case creation and update existing case comments and prevent field update to fire.

Comment: do the outbound emails include the thread id?  if yes, replies won't create new Cases. If no, add the thread ID into the email template

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing Thead Id when you are sending emails to Customer.

Have a look into this Knowledge article.
[Why is the email to case generating new cases from reply emails?](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004218)

If you want to update existing case comments based on Customer response you could use InboundEmail object to parse the response and put that in Case comments.

Comment: You can generate the thread id yourself if the standard way ( Setup-> Customize -> Cases -> Email to case -> Send Emails From Cases section) does not meet your use case by creating a formula field to mimic how Salesforce generates it. This is a great article that explains how: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008lCcIAI

Comment: @PavanTej is that the issue got resolved?